# Recover the question.. of another user

Tags: support, undelete

Just a few minutes ago, I answered the question of a member on StackOverflow, however we had a very long discussion by comments since I could not open a chat for some reason. Therefore, I told the OP to delete its comments and did the same. However, the OP deleted the **question** ! Luckily, I had the question open in two tabs and I could save the page on my disk.

The question was asked by *user4186509* one hour ago. Is that possible to recover it or to contact him ?

Comment: which site? and the only real way to contact another member is in chat, no personal messaging.

Comment: I created a room and added him to the writers, but I don't think he will be notified

Comment: A poster can delete their own question, with very few exceptions. You can not undelete it if they chose to do so. The question about whether or not you can directly contact someone has been asked here many times before.

Comment: @KenWhite 10K users can vote to undelete self-deleted questions; such undeletions happened on occasions.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii: As I said, **with few exceptions**. The times it has happened would be among those exceptions.

Comment: @KenWhite Your "exceptions" clause is in the sentence about poster's ability to delete own question. The statement "you cannot undelete if the chose to do so" is incorrect.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii: No, it's not. See the linked duplicate. A poster can delete their own question the majority of the time, unless there are certain circumstances that prevent it (accepted answers being one). I don't know what you're arguing about - the linked question explains it all, and this question is now closed.

Comment: The question has been recovered, I think I have to thank Flexo for this. Thanks also to the others who responded here